# How to change Grocery Crud text editor with bootstrap summernote

Tags: summernote, grocery-crud

Hi everyone I got some problem with my text editor in Grocery Crud. In my default text editor I couldn't upload image into the editor so I think I want to change default text editor with bootstrap summernote. But the problem is how to I to do that ? I have downloaded bootstrap summernote and I stuck now I don't know to add the bootstrap summernote to Grocery Crud library and change the default editor with bootstrap summernote.

Answer (score 1):

for custom text editor you will add your editor files in grocery crud library:

find this function on `Grocery_CRUD.php` in library folder

```
get_text_input()
```

and add your custom editor files in switch for example:

```
case 'youreditor':
                $this->set_css($this->default_texteditor_path.'youreditor/style.css');

                $this->set_js_lib($this->default_texteditor_path.'/youreditor/youreditor.js');
                $this->set_js_config($this->default_javascript_path.'/jquery_plugins/config/jquery.youreditor.config.js');
                break;
```

and end go to grocery crud config file and edit this line:

```
$config['grocery_crud_default_text_editor'] = 'youreditor';
```

update:

`$this->set_js_config` is optional and you can save and call this file from
`assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/config`

and default text editor root in here

[image: Files Root]